# Custom templates for SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-templates

What is the correct folder name to store a [custom Item Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx) for a [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) Database Project?

eg. What sub-folder should it live in under C:\Users\accountname\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Templates\ItemTemplates

The SSDT-provided templates seem to be located under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer

(For VS2010, substitute '10' for '11' in the paths above)

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: No, I don't think I did

Answer (score -2):

You save the Template RDL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject . Then it will be available in 'Add > New report' window.

Comment: That might work for RDL files, but it isn't under the user's directory though

Comment: For Templates (.dtsx) files, you can use:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject\DataTransformationItems. Hope it helps :)