# Change Stored Procedure Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

Basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590152/visual-studio-2010-how-to-change-stored-procedure-template), except for Visual Studio 2013.  How do I change the Stored Procedure template in Visual Studio 2013?  I have an SQL file already that I use in SSMS, but want to replace the one in VS.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600541/custom-templates-for-ssdt) is also related, though it is unanswered, and for VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it.  The templates for Visual Studio 2013 are located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\Items
```

Just plop in whatever appropriately named SQL file you want, and the New {Whatever} dialog uses your new file.

Comment: Do you know how to add and use new custom templates for new SQL stored procedure instead of replacing the use only the existing one?

i don't want it to be replaced when upgrading VS.

Comment: @Omtechguy Sorry, no, I do not. I'm sure it's possible though.

Comment: There are built-in templates in the Template Browser found in the View Menu. From there, you can use the templates provided (Alter, Create, and Drop templates for Stored Procedures already exist here by default) or you can create your own. These can also be exported for backups in case of loss.